# How to say "this word is pronounces as"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

I have a text in which I need to write a non-Englsih word, in an English text. I will write the word in its native non-English language. However, I want to follow it with the English pronounciation. Is there a common phrase to say the word is pronounced as ...

For example:

> He said Oui [here I want to tell the reader, this word is pronounces
> as "we"]

Comment: In French you might say _un mot se prononce comme..._ but in English we use the verb 'to be' and a participle - this word **is pronounced...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MichaelWokeHarvey [commented...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305905/how-to-say-this-word-is-pronounces-as#comment572423_305905)

> In French you might say *un mot se prononce comme...* but in English we use the verb 'to be' and a participle - *this word is **pronounced***

There are lots of contexts with lots of verbs where the French version is ***reflexive*** (in this case, "the word" literally "pronounces itself", so it's both the subject and the object), but in English we're more likely to use a ***passive*** construction (some unspecified subject does the pronouncing of the word).